# Mobile Safari input focus leaves artifacts of elements in previous position

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari

This issue is particularly difficult to explain...

In Mobile Safari (and not in Chrome on Android), when an input is focused and the view adjusts to put the input in the center of the screen, I've noticed that sometimes the elements that were previously there still have their touch events in place.

See the video below, in which I click slightly above the "apply" button, which ends up clicking on the "total price" header, which causes the dropdown to collapse. Obviously, that ghost touch event should not be there.

Basically, when I focus on the input, the screen moves as expected, but the touch events for the elements that were there before don;t move with them. If I touch in the same place that an element used to be, it triggers that event.

https://youtu.be/5tFNfnd5RO4

I know for sure that the event being triggered here is the one for the "total price" bar, because if I click slightly below it to the right, I can trigger the event for the "change" button.

Note that this doesn't happen consistently. I cannot replicate this 100% of the time, but I was able to capture it on video.

Comment: This appears to be related to the bug mentioned in this Hacker Noon article: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-fix-the-ios-11-input-element-in-fixed-modals-bug-aaf66c7ba3f8

Comment: Appears related to these as well:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=176896
https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2018/01/apple-previews-ios-11-3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in iOS and they say they're going to fix it in the 11.3 release.

https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2018/01/apple-previews-ios-11-3/